# $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n} \forall n>1$

Tags: general-topology

> Theorem: $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n} \forall n>1$

To prove this, all that is required is to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$ is separated and $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus {y}$ is connected.
However, I'm facing a bit of an issue as to how it can be shown that $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus {y}$ is path connected.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Of related interest.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2010834/170039)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $y$ be $0$ in $\mathbb R ^n$; now you can connect two points with a convex combination if the segment that connects them does not pass through the origin; if it passes through the origin, than consider a plane that contains the two points and the origin, now you can consider the triangle that connects the two points and not passes through the origin, so it's done.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is disconnected whereas $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is not.

$\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is in fact path connected.

To see this take any two points $a,b\in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. We can find uncountable number of straight lines passing through $a$.

Now it is quite obvious to find a straight line joining through $a$ and $b$ without passing through $0$.

Comment: I don't find it quite as obvious as you do

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Fact}$: The product of two path connected spaces is path connected: $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{y\} \cong S^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}$